# Include check value of bean in struts jsp file

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have an iterator in my jsp defined like so -

```
<s:iterator value="eventList" var="event">
```

How can I check the value of eventList ?

Something like -

```
if(eventList.size > 0){

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Struts2 should never be referred to as struts confuses people, the s:iterator tag is only in S2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<s:if test="eventList.size() > 0">
</s:if>
```